# Can I open a socket and pass it to another process in Linux

Tags: linux, sockets

In Linux, is it possible for me to open a socket and pass the socket to another process?
If yes, can you please tell me where I can find an example?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I share a file descriptor to another process on linux or are they local to the process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358684/can-i-share-a-file-descriptor-to-another-process-on-linux-or-are-they-local-to-t)

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' you're linking to a auestion that was asked chronologically after this one how can it be a duplicate?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Yes you can, using `sendmsg()` with SCM_RIGHTS from one process to another:

> `SCM_RIGHTS` - Send or receive a set of
>   open file descriptors from another
>   process. The data portion contains an
>   integer array of the file descriptors.
>   The passed file descriptors behave as
>   though they have been created with
>   `dup(2)`.

http://linux.die.net/man/7/unix

That is not the typical usage though. More common is when a process inherits sockets from its parent (after a `fork()`). Any file handles (including sockets) not closed will be available to the child process. So the child process inherits the parent's sockets.

A server process that listens for connections is called a daemon. This usually forks on each new connection, spawning a process to handle each new request. An example of the typical daemon is here:

http://www.steve.org.uk/Reference/Unix/faq_8.html#SEC88

Scroll down to void `process()`.

Comment: Unless you don't want to fork a new process for every request but just pass the request on to a set of workers.

Comment: This looks specific to AF_UNIX. Can this be done for TCP sockets?

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala: no, you can't send a socket (or file handle) over TCP to another machine, they must stay within the same kernel. So the channel over which you communicate must be AF_UNIX, but the file handle you transfer can of course be a TCP socket.

Comment: @Zarat, OK, good, naturally you can't send them across machines.  I somehow got it into my head that only AF_UNIX sockets could be transferred.  Stupid of me - the man page is actually perfectly clear.

Comment: What if both of the processes are also reading from the socket what happens ?

Comment: Another good example where socket is passed by a sentinel process to other processes is https://github.com/zimbatm/socketmaster