# Share socket between unrelated processes like systemd

Tags: linux, sockets, share, file-descriptor, systemd

There are multiple questions and answers how to do it, but both processes must cooperate

- [Can I open a socket and pass it to another process in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997622/can-i-open-a-socket-and-pass-it-to-another-process-in-linux)
- [Share socket (listen) between unrelated processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438063/share-socket-listen-between-unrelated-processes)
- [Portable way to pass file descriptor between different processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909064/portable-way-to-pass-file-descriptor-between-different-processes)

etc.

In `systemd`, there is feature [socket activation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html), you just have opened and prepared file descriptotr in your process without any cooperation. You can just use file descriptor `3` (`SD_LISTEN_FDS_START`) and it is already activated socket by systemd.

How does `systemd` do this? I can't find any relevant source code.

**Edit:**

I know, how to write systemd socket activated service, but I'm interested in the process of passing file descriptor to my service form the `systemd` point of view.

E.g. if I would like to write my own socket activator, that behaves exactly as systemd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`systemd` is **not unrelated** to the processes who share the sockets. `systemd` starts up and supervises the entire system, so it can pass the socket file descriptors during `exec()` easily. `systemd` listens on behalf of the services and whenever a connection would come in, an instance of the respective service would be spawned. [Here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/activate/activate.c#L498) is the implementation:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) {
        int r, n;
        int epoll_fd = -1; 

        log_parse_environment();
        log_open();

        r = parse_argv(argc, argv);
        if (r <= 0)
                return r == 0 ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;

        r = install_chld_handler();
        if (r < 0)
                return EXIT_FAILURE;

        n = open_sockets(&epoll_fd, arg_accept);
        if (n < 0)
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        if (n == 0) {
                log_error("No sockets to listen on specified or passed in.");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        for (;;) {
                struct epoll_event event;

                r = epoll_wait(epoll_fd, &event, 1, -1);
                if (r < 0) {
                        if (errno == EINTR)
                                continue;

                        log_error_errno(errno, "epoll_wait() failed: %m");
                        return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }

                log_info("Communication attempt on fd %i.", event.data.fd);
                if (arg_accept) {
                        r = do_accept(argv[optind], argv + optind, envp, event.data.fd);
                        if (r < 0)
                                return EXIT_FAILURE;
                } else
                        break;
        }
        ...
}
```

Once a connection comes in, it will call `do_accept()`:

```
static int do_accept(const char* name, char **argv, char **envp, int fd) {
        _cleanup_free_ char *local = NULL, *peer = NULL;
        _cleanup_close_ int fd_accepted = -1; 

        fd_accepted = accept4(fd, NULL, NULL, 0); 
        if (fd_accepted < 0)
                return log_error_errno(errno, "Failed to accept connection on fd:%d: %m", fd);

        getsockname_pretty(fd_accepted, &local);
        getpeername_pretty(fd_accepted, true, &peer);
        log_info("Connection from %s to %s", strna(peer), strna(local));

        return fork_and_exec_process(name, argv, envp, fd_accepted);
}
```

finally, [it](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/activate/activate.c#L261) calls `execvpe(name, argv, envp);` and wrap the fd up in `envp`. There is a trick in it, if `fd_accepted` is not equal to `SD_LISTEN_FDS_START`, it call [`dup2()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) to makes `SD_LISTEN_FDS_START` be the copy of `fd_accepted`:

```
    if (start_fd != SD_LISTEN_FDS_START) {
            assert(n_fds == 1);

            r = dup2(start_fd, SD_LISTEN_FDS_START);
            if (r < 0)
                    return log_error_errno(errno, "Failed to dup connection: %m");

            safe_close(start_fd);
            start_fd = SD_LISTEN_FDS_START;
    }
```

So you can just use file descriptor 3 like this in your application, `sd_listen_fds` will parse the environment variable `LISTEN_FDS` passed from `envp`:

```
int listen_sock;
int fd_count = sd_listen_fds(0);
if (fd_count == 1) { // assume one socket only
  listen_sock = SD_LISTEN_FDS_START; // SD_LISTEN_FDS_START is a macro defined to 3
} else {
  // error
}
struct sockaddr addr;
socklen_t addrlen;
while (int client_sock = accept(listen_sock, &addr, &addrlen)) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: This is clear to me, but what am I interested in is the process of passing the file descriptor during `exec()` without cooperation of the process being executed.

Comment: Thank you for the extended answer. I must investigate it little bit. For me, processes are still unrelated, but there are two important tricks for me. By default, file descriptors remain open across an `execve()`. This is new to me. Second trick is `dup2()` function that do the final move of the fd.

Comment: Note that close-on-exec flag is set in `open_sockets()`, but after `dup2()`, the two file descriptors do not share file descriptor flags (the close-on-exec flag), so close-on-exec flag for `fd_accepted` is off.